# How to map EXIT CODE 2 in spring batch when input file is not located at the source folder

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

I have to map exit code 2 whenever input file is not located in the source folder in spring batch.I have tried by implementing listener but batch terminate before starting and return exit code 1. It doesn't reach to the listener to map it with exit code 2. So can someone help me in that.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any log is coming?

Comment: @Binu It is giving illegalargumentexception:source cannot be null.

Comment: copy the stack trace

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you mean the `EXIT_CODE` in the `BATCH_STEP_EXECUTION` table, not the exit code from like `System.exit(int x)`.

In that case, it's probably easier to just change the reader not to throw the Exception (and instead just return `null` when the `read()` method executes. The `FlatFileItemReader` makes this easy by just setting the `strict` property to false.

---

If you meant the actual JVM exit code (which is pretty gross), then you'd basically have to register a `StepExecutionListener` and then inform the calling class that the failure occurred... **please note:** I don't recommend this pattern

```
// In MainClass
private static final AtomicBoolean fileNotFound = new AtomicBoolean(false);

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // launch job

    if (fileNotFound.get()) {
        System.exit(2);
    }
}

public static void setFileNotFound(boolean bool) {
    fileNotFound.set(bool);
}

// In StepExecutionListener
public void afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    for (Throwable error : stepExecution.getFailureExceptions()) {
        if (error instanceof IllegalArgumentException && "source cannot be null".equals(error.getMessage())) {
            MainClass.setFileNotFound(true);
        }
    }
}
```